# Doctrine2 : "Class doesn't exist" ReflectionException, classpath duplication

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

So I have a Many to One to One to Many relationship between two entities A and B. To get all entities B that match with one specific A. C is the class that makes the link between A and B.

```
$bs = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getEntityManager()
                    ->getRepository('MyBundle:C')
                    ->findByContact($a->getId());
```

So this part is probably working, but when I execute it it makes this error :

> Class My\Bundle\Entity\My\Bundle\Entity\D does not exist

So D is a class that is in a One to Many relationship with B. It is only natural that it's called when the repository gets a list of B.

But why does it duplicate the path of the entity?

Note : I have searched for the calls of class D, but the path is never duplicated anywhere in my code.

Edit :

After spending a while trying to see what paths were at the origin of the problem, I finally came a cross a really minor (but important) difference between Doctrine annotation paths, which are basically :

> My\Bundle\Entity\D

and the path that is called for the class in the php itself, especially in getters and setters :

> \My\Bundle\Entity\D

That backslash has been holding me for a long time here, but now everything works again.
Problem solved.

Comment: What's your Entity files look like?